# Dictionary value to Data table c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

```
Allocation of Race[3]~Brown County,Total:~6866,Allocated~315,Not allocated~6551
Allocation of Age[3]~Brown County,Total:~6866,Allocated~315,Not allocated~6551
Allocation of Race[3]~Boone County,Total:~6866,Allocated~315,Not allocated~6551
Allocation of Age[3]~Boone County,Total:~6866,Allocated~315,Not allocated~6551
```

Above is my dictionary key value pair.

Key = Allocation of Race[3]~Brown County &&
Value= Total:~6866,Allocated~315,Not allocated~6551

I am trying to insert these values into a datatable

```
  table.Columns.Add("Topic");
  table.Columns.Add("County");
  table.Columns.Add("Header");
  table.Columns.Add("Value");
```

In my key value pair, topic = Allocation of Race[3] && County = Brown County && Header = Total, allocated and Not allocated and value = their respective values.

Initially, I tried to split the key pair using

```
  string[] Topic_County = key.Split('~');
```

so Topic_County consists of
[0] = Allocation of Race[3]
[1]= County name

```
  foreach (string tc in Topic_County)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(tc);    
            }
```

when i use foreach loop, allocation of race and county name are coming in the same column
How can I add county name under county column, and its header and value in respective positions.

Comment: Consider redesigning your data structure

Comment: Can you please suggest me best possible way to display dictionary elements on the webpage

Comment: It appears you're using `Dictionary<string,string>` Try to change it to `Dictionary<SomeStruct,SomeClass>`. Some struct will be immutable type. SomeClass will have Total, allocated and not allocated properties. You need to use `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` for your struct to compare.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple class like this:

```
public class Datum
{
    public string Topic = "";
    public string County = "";
    public int Allocated = 0;
    public int NotAllocated = 0;

    public int Total()
    {
        return Allocated + NotAllocated;
    }
}
```

You could use a dictionary still, just use the Topic property and the County property as the key:

```
        Dictionary<string, Datum> MyData = new Dictionary<string, Datum>();
        Datum info = new Datum
        {
            Topic = "Allocation of Race[3]",
            County = "Brown County",
            Allocated = 315,
            NotAllocated = 6551
        };
        MyData.Add(info.Topic + "-" + info.County, info);
```

Though a List would probably work just as well and with LINQ you can extract any of the items you need grouped or ordered by whatever criteria you set.

Since Total is a method you don't need to add it to the dictionary just call it as a member of Datum whenever you need the value.

You could add the data to the datatable like this:

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Topic");
        table.Columns.Add("County");
        table.Columns.Add("Allocated");
        table.Columns.Add("Not Allocated");
        table.Columns.Add("Total");
        foreach(Datum entry in MyData.Values)
        {
            DataRow NewDataRow = table.NewRow();
            NewDataRow.ItemArray = new string[5]
            {
                entry.Topic,
                entry.County,
                entry.Allocated.ToString(),
                entry.NotAllocated.ToString(),
                entry.Total().ToString()
            };
            table.Rows.Add(NewDataRow);
        }
```